# Making a simple flexible translate function in nodejs

Tags: json, node.js

In nodejs I have these (very long) translation files

gb.json (english)

```
{
    "transHi":"Hello",
    "transBye":"Goodbye"
}
```

de.json (german)

```
{
    "transHi":"Gutentag",
    "transBye":"Auf Wiedersehen"
}
```

I have a lot of controllers that all need these texts available in the many languages so I can call them when ever needed.

The obvious way would be something like this in my app.js:

```
global.gb = require('../global/language/gb.json');
global.de = require('../global/language/de.json');
```

And when I need a text I would call like:

```
myText = global.gb.transHi  
myText = global.de.transHi
```

But!! the language is always determined by a variable

```
usersLanguage = "de"
myText = global.usersLanguage.transHi
```

And that wont work.

I also tried:

```
usersLanguage = "de"
myText = global.usersLanguage.transHi
```

Perhaps I could solve it with a function that has a long switch structure

```
var findText = (language,textkey) => {
    switch(language) {
        case "gb:
            return gb.textkey
            break;
        case "de:
            return de.textkey
            break;
    }
}

myText = translate(usersLanguage, "transHi");
```

But I cant seem to make that work either.

How would I do this in a simple and flexible way?

UPDATE:  Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any object property accessed via `.` can also be accessed using array index notation `[]`. So,

```
var langObj = texts.gb;
```

is the same as

```
var langObj = texts["gb"];
```

which is also the same as

```
var lang = "gb";
var langObj = texts[lang];
```

Same for the textkey, using the `.textkey` you get the property called `textkey`, which probably doesn't exist. If you want a different property depending on the value of the variable `textkey`, do

```
var text = langObj[textkey];
```

Comment: Arrrrgh!!! hahaha Aurel - that was exactly what I needed!!!  Except I did `global.[lang].transAboutText` which gave an error.  Thanks!!!  I feel silly now for not seeing that hehehehe :-D